# Where can I find a list of configuration properties for Spring Redis

Tags: spring, redis, spring-data-redis

I tried looking at [the reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/reference/html/#reference) but I can't seem to find a complete list of `spring.redis` configuration values.

I am looking specifically for setting the prefix for Spring Data Redis operations.